# Solid guage highchart graph integration with angular 4

Tags: git, angular, charts, gauge

I am trying to do the integration of angular 4 with highchart. I am able to get the simple charts like barchart etc. But when trying to implement the solid guage getting the below error:

```
ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:248)
    at highcharts.js:271
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

As per suggesions in other posts I have added the below code in appmodule.ts

    declare var require: any;
    export function highchartsFactory() {

        var hc = require('highcharts');
        var hcm = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
        var sg = require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge');

        hcm(hc);
        sg(hc);

        return hc;
    }


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [
     .....
        ChartModule
      ],
      providers: [ {provide: HighchartsStatic,useFactory: highchartsFactory}],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { 
}
```

Git Hub Repository URL : https://github.com/AbhishekKaura25/solid-guage-demo

Comment: edited the code formatting + tags

Comment: Have same issue. Any resolution?  Argument of type '{ chart: { type: string; }; title: { text: string; }; tooltip: { enabled: boolean; }; pane: { cen...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Types of property 'pane' are incompatible.
   Type '{ center: string[]; size: string; startAngle: number; endAngle: number; background: { backgroundC...' is not assignable t
o type 'PaneOptions'.
      Types of property 'center' are incompatible.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string | number, string | number]'.
          Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]'.

Answer (score 0):

This is an official example form angular2-highcharts, and it works well for me.

[plnkr.co/edit/tLK6seWvqYBAl3QA7ayF?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLK6seWvqYBAl3QA7ayF?p=preview)

I had the same problem and very similar error message, just change your code into the follow works for me.

```
declare var require: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
 .....
    ChartModule.forRoot(
      require('highcharts'),
      require('highcharts/modules/exporting'),
      require('highcharts/highcharts-more'),
      require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge')
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
```